# What is the state of the algorithmic art for floating point arithmetic on complex numbers?

Tags: reference-request, floating-point, numerical-algorithms, error-estimation

Most modern compilers and processors implement the IEEE 754 binary formats for floating point numbers. IEEE 754 guarantees that the addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and square root operations on real floating point values are *correctly rounded*, meaning that the result of each operation is as if the operation were computed to infinite precision and then subsequently rounded according to the specified rounding mode (most commonly [round to nearest, ties to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even)). In other words, it is guaranteed for these operations that the final floating point number is as close as possible to the true value of the operation given the mathematical values of the input floating point numbers.

A number of programming languages also offer *complex* floating point arithmetic. Addition and subtraction of complex floating point numbers can obviously guarantee correct rounding (treating the rounding mode as applying to each component separately), since these operations can be computed componentwise. Surely then, I assumed, the correct rounding guarantee also applies to common language-provided implementations of complex multiplication, division, and square root?

So far, I have found no evidence that this is the case, and a fair amount of evidence to the contrary. For example, this recent paper provides examples of wildly incorrect results that can be obtained from naive attempts at computing complex multiplication via multiple floating point roundings, and describes an algorithm for complex multiplication that produces results accurate to within 2 ulps (but not guaranteed 100% *correctly rounded* as defined above).

> Claude-Pierre Jeannerod, Christophe Monat, Laurent Thévenoux (2017). [More accurate complex multiplication for embedded processors](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01512760v2/document). SIES 2017.

This suggests that there is no standard/widely-used sequence of fused multiply-add tricks for doing complex multiplication with correct rounding. I've also found several references to the difficulty of computing complex division in a numerically-stable fashion.

**Question 1:** Given floating point inputs and outputs with $n$ exponent bits and $m$ significand bits, what is the best-known worst case time complexity for computing the *correctly-rounded* values of complex multiplication, division, and square root?

**Question 2:** Are any references available for methods for computing these complex operations with *correct rounding* using the real floating point operations available on a standard FPU?

Comment: Currently looking at Jean-Michel Muller et al's _Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic_, which appears to cover these issues in section 4.5.

Comment: If you could add an answer summarizing what you find out, that would be awesome!

Comment: The _Handbook_ gives a number of error bounds on simple methods of computing complex multiply/divide/sqrt, but does not appear to provide algorithms for these that guarantee correct rounding. Currently looking into papers related to ``crlibm`` to see if I can find any info that would allow exact computation even of complex multiplication.

Comment: I believe that the components of complex multiplication can be computed with correct rounding by doing two double × double → double-double multiplies, then a double-double × double-double → quad-double add, and finally a correct rounding on the quad-double. No word on complex division or sqrt yet.

Comment: If you store the complex numbers in polar form then multiplication inherits the guarantees you get from real floating point arithmetic for free.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury If by 'for free' you mean 'losing the guarantees for addition/subtraction', sure. It's one or the other.

Comment: @Aaron Rotenberg Your findings and impressions are accurate, and to the best of my knowledge the answers to your questions are: (1) open research problem (2) no. There is very little work happening in this space, and I know of no library or paper that shows how to guarantee correctly rounded results.

Comment: @njuffa That's quite remarkable to me, given how many programming languages (C99, C++, MATLAB, C#, Ada, Haskell...) offer complex floating point arithmetic in their standard libraries!

Comment: @AaronRotenberg Two issues: (1) research costs money, and hardly any entity appears to want to pay for this particular research; the hot topics du jour attracting money are elsewhere. IMHO, the French teams are our best chance of forward progress in this space (2) When it comes to floating-point computation, my experience is that language users complain about lack of performance much more frequently than lack of accuracy, so in industry R&D much of the "D" goes into performance optimizations.

Comment: @njuffa: I'd think that if you calculate the mantissas with say 192 bit integer arithmetic and rounding, it should be possible to prove that every result would be correctly rounded. There are similar proofs for sine / cosine for example where for some rather large n, n-bit arithmetic is guaranteed to give the correctly rounded result.

Comment: @njuffa There's also the question how much benefit you get from proving that the result is correctly (which means error <= 0.5u), rather than error < 0.51u for example.

Comment: @gnasher729 The biggest benefit is in precision of language/library specifications. Instead of saying the operation returns an unspecified, implementation-defined value with error less than such-and-such, you just say the operation returns _the best possible_ value. Also, having the correct rounding guarantee makes it easier to prove certain properties, e.g. correctness of interval arithmetic using directional rounding modes.

Comment: @AaronRotenberg  Vincent Lefèvre and Jean-Michel Muller, "Accurate Complex Multiplication in Floating-Point Arithmetic", January 31, 2019 ([online](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02001080/)) "Abstract : We deal with accurate complex multiplication in binary floating-point arithmetic, with an emphasis on the case where one of the operands in a "double-word" number. We provide an algorithm that returns a complex product with normwise relative error bound close to the best possible one, i.e., the rounding unit u"